# Why gridview in Gallery app of the system dose not use viewholder?

Tags: android, gridview

As a junior Android app developer, I know when we use a `gridview` or `listview` we should use the ViewHolder to optimalize the performance. When I want to build a gridview with multi selection, I find the selected views are changed after scrolling the gridview, so I want to know how does the [system gallery](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery/+/android-m-preview-1/src/com/android/camera/GalleryPicker.java) achieve this purpose. But from the `getView()` funtion in `GalleryPickerAdapter` I can see it does not use the ViewHolder, why the google engineer does not use ViewHolder?

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
    View v;
    if (convertView == null) {
        v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_picker_item, null);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }
    TextView titleView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
    GalleryPickerItem iv =
            (GalleryPickerItem) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    Item item = mItems.get(position);
    iv.setOverlay(item.getOverlay());
    if (item.mThumbBitmap != null) {
        iv.setImageBitmap(item.mThumbBitmap);
        String title = item.mName + " (" + item.mCount + ")";
        titleView.setText(title);
    } else {
        iv.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        titleView.setText(item.mName);
    }
    // An workaround due to a bug in TextView. If the length of text is
    // different from the previous in convertView, the layout would be
    // wrong.
    titleView.requestLayout();
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewHolder is not a thing that **must** be implemented in gridview and listview but it's only a good approach to save time during findViewById.

Now you could implement [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) that force you to use [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder.html).

Comment: ViewHolder can save memory allocation, can't it?

Comment: ViewHolder saves time that needed for findViewById. Memory is saved by reusing items in convertView.

Comment: Is that mean                                                                                                   `if (convertView == null) {  v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_picker_item, null);
    } else {
        v = convertView;
    }` can save memory, and the ViewHolder just saves time

Comment: I get it, ViewHolder is basically is a storage that has reference to Views, so I won't have to do binding once again (findViewById) , thanks